# Finding minimal area of a cylindrically symmetric surface

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am told that I have a cylindrically symmetric surface that is bounded between two circles $r=a$ at $z=\pm b$. 
I'm meant to use the Euler-Lagrange equation, so I'm trying to a functional for the area of a given surface. I tried to find the surface area element of the cylindrical surface by taking the cross product of $\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r}$ but this gives me $dS=r\sqrt{2(z')^2+1}drd\theta$ which I don't think is right and doesn't really help me.

Comment: There must be another constraint, otherwise, $r=0$ would give a trivial minimum. Oh, wait, is this supposed to be $r=a$ at both $z=b$ and $z=-b$? That will give something more interesting.

Comment: Yes, r=a at z=b and z=-b.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pappus's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem) or the formula for the [Area of a Surface of Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula), we get
$$
A=\int_{-b}^b2\pi r\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\delta A
&=\delta\int_{-b}^b2\pi r\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi\int_{-b}^b\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z
+2\pi\int_{-b}^br\frac{r'\delta r'}{\sqrt{r'^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi\int_{-b}^b\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z
-2\pi\int_{-b}^b\left(\frac{rr''+r'^2}{\sqrt{r'^2+1}}-\frac{rr'r'r''}{\sqrt{r'^2+1}^3}\right)\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi\int_{-b}^b\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z
-2\pi\int_{-b}^b\frac{rr''+r'^2+r'^4}{\sqrt{r'^2+1}^3}\,\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi\int_{-b}^b\frac{r'^2-rr''+1}{\sqrt{r'^2+1}^3}\,\delta r\,\mathrm{d}z\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, to get $\delta A=0$ for any $\delta r$, we need $r'^2-rr''+1=0\iff\frac1{r^2}=\left(\frac{r'}r\right)'$.

Let $cr=\cosh(t)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{r^2}&=\left(\frac{r'}r\right)'\\
\frac{r'}{r^3}&=\left(\frac{r'}r\right)'\frac{r'}r\\
c^2-\frac1{r^2}&=\left(\frac{r'}r\right)^2\\
\sqrt{c^2r^2-1}&=r'\\
cz&=\int\frac{c\,\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{c^2r^2-1}}\\
cz+d&=t
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $r=\frac1c\cosh(cz+d)$. To be symmetric about $z=0$, we let $d=0$. Thus, to have $r(b)=a$ we need to solve $ac=\cosh(bc)$, then
$$
r=\frac1c\cosh(cz)
$$

Comment: Yeah; I am fine with how to solve the problem once I've found the surface area element-  I should be able to arrive at the first part of your solution without using Pappus's Theorem.

Comment: The cylindrical surface area element can be taken to be $$r\sqrt{r'^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$ where $r$ is a function of $z$. In this case, this leads directly to Pappus's Theorem.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't understand how to reach that expression.

Comment: @Guest195: Computing the [area of a surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula) is usually handled before Calculus of Variations. Take a look at the link.